# Google Cloud IAP behind reverse proxy

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, proxy, google-cloud-platform

I would like to enable Google Cloud IAP to control access to App Engine, and use it behind an external reverse proxy.

For example:

`https://my-domain.com` >> `https://my-domain.appspot.com`

I have the external (nginx) proxy configured as follows:

```
location /
{

    set $target             my-domain.appspot.com;

    proxy_pass              https://$target;
    proxy_set_header        Host $target;

    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    proxy_intercept_errors  on;

}
```

Cloud IAP, however, redirects me to `my-domain.appspot.com` after logging in.

Is there any additional configuration I am missing?